# Selenium python to locate an element and print its attribute

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to webscrape this particular website - [Link to the Page](https://app.thestorefront.com/listings?address=New%20York,%20NY,%20USA&page=2). I would like to webscrape the data-listing-id for each of the properties. Kindly see the Image to see the element which I am trying to locate. I couldn't post my HTML as its a lot more complicated. [image]

Here is the sample code that I tried -

```
driver.get("https://app.thestorefront.com/listings?address=New%20York,%20NY,%20USA&page=1")
Container=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("listing-panel")
for index in Container:
    a= index.find_element_by_class_name("favourite-tag.ng-isolate-scope")
    print(a)
    for index2 in a:
        b= index2.get_attribute("data-listing-id")
```

and the result was unable to locate the element a. Kindly give me your suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Few remarks about your code: 1. You're trying to iterate through `a` while `a` is a web-element, but not an iterable object. 2. `b` will be overwriten on each iteration. Do you want to create a list and to append all of `b` values?

Comment: Ya ! thanx @Andersson. I got your point !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast way to do this is to just find all the elements that have the attribute you are looking for. From what I can tell, only the elements you want have that attribute.

```
driver.get("https://app.thestorefront.com/listings?address=New%20York,%20NY,%20USA&page=1")
for e in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[data-listing-id]")
    print(e.get_attribute("data-listing-id"))
```

Comment: Wow !! This is so perfect ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To build off of what Andersson was saying, you need to find all elements and not just one. You are also mixing up your selector. I'd suggest just using css_selector:

```
driver.get("https://app.thestorefront.com/listings?address=New%20York,%20NY,%20USA&page=1")
Container=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("listing-panel")
for index in Container:
    a= index.find_elements_by_css_selector(".favourite-tag.ng-isolate-scope")
    print(a)
    for index2 in a:
        b= index2.get_attribute("data-listing-id")
```